# Is it legal to buy raw gold in South africa?

Tags: commerce

Is it legal to buy raw gold in South Africa?
I see someone is selling it on Facebook and I want to make a ring for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a license, it is legal. See the [Precious Metals Act, 2005](https://www.gov.za/sites/default/files/gcis_document/201409/a37-050.pdf) in particular §4 which says that

> no person may acquire, possess or
> dispose of, either as principal or as agent, any unwrought precious metal, unless (a) he or she is the holder of a
> refining licence and acts in accordance with the terms and conditions
> of his or her licence; (b) he or she is an authorised dealer; (c) he
> or she is a producer who has won or recovered such unwrought precious
> metal; (4 he or she has obtained a certificate from the Regulator
> authorising him or her to acquire or to dispose of such unwrought
> precious metal; (e) such unwrought precious metal does not exceed a
> prescribed mass and is acquired in accordance with a special permit
> issued by the Regulator for scientific or beneficiation purposes or to
> make jewellery; or he or she is the holder of a precious metal
> beneficiation licence and acts in accordance with the terms and
> conditions of his or her licence

Subsection (e) still requires a permit or license.